# Open project from Sublime Text to new tab in iTerm (not to new window)

Tags: sublimetext, iterm

I've been using the [Terminal](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/MacTerminal) package to quickly open terminal from Sublime Text. Only problem is that it opens it to a new window in iTerm, not to a new tab.

Is there a way to force it to open to a new tab?

From the [docs](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/terminal):

> With the parameters argument to the open_terminal and open_terminal_project_folder commands, it is possible to construct custom terminal environments.

Can I somehow use the "parameters" in the setting to accomplish this?

Here's the default settings:

```
{
    // The command to execute for the terminal, leave blank for the OS default
    // On OS X the terminal can be set to iTerm.sh to execute iTerm
    "terminal": "iTerm.sh",

    // A list of default parameters to pass to the terminal, this can be
    // overridden by passing the "parameters" key with a list value to the args
    // dict when calling the "open_terminal" or "open_terminal_project_folder"
    // commands
    "parameters": []
}
```

Comment: I have just found this PR that should solve this :) https://github.com/wbond/sublime_terminal/pull/69

Comment: After investigating more, I found out that MacTerminal package does this by default https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/MacTerminal

Answer (score 2):

Edit the iTerm.sh in Packages/Terminal folder

```
if (( $RUNNING )); then
    osascript<<END
    tell application "iTerm"
        activate
        tell the first terminal
            set sess to (launch session "Default Session")
            tell sess
                write text "$CD_CMD"
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
END
```

it works for me

Answer (score 2):

You can config Terminal Package Setting like this:

```
{
    // The command to execute for the terminal, leave blank for the OS default
    // On OS X the terminal can be set to iTerm.sh to execute iTerm
    "terminal": "iTerm.sh",

    // A list of default parameters to pass to the terminal, this can be
    // overridden by passing the "parameters" key with a list value to the args
    // dict when calling the "open_terminal" or "open_terminal_project_folder"
    // commands
    "parameters": ["--open-in-tab"]
}
```